# How to combine exact search and wildcard in elasticsearch simple_query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "\"sometext*\"",
        "fields": ["name"],
        "default_operator": "and",
        "quote_field_suffix": '.raw',
        "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  }
}
```

but the search result is incorrect.

for example, there is an index:

1. prefixsometext
2. sometextone
3. sometexttwo

I need to find only 2 and 3 when querying "sometext*"

Comment: I need to do this in simple_query_string, because other operators are needed too, for example, " \"sometext*\" | ( othertext -excludetext ) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcard are slow, you can use match_phrase_prefix instead

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "text": "sometext"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index20",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7tdM7XEBxsgtRl4gFK-i",
        "_score" : 0.9808291,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "sometextone"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index20",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "79dM7XEBxsgtRl4gJq8Z",
        "_score" : 0.9808291,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "sometexttwo"
        }
      }
    ]
```

In simple_query_string  quotes  denote exact phrase match so "\"sometextone\"" will return result but if you need to do prefix match , query has to be defined as "query": "sometext*"

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "sometext*",
        "fields": ["name"],
        "default_operator": "and",
        "quote_field_suffix": '.raw',
        "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  }
}
```

To replicate query in your comment using bool query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "FIELD": "PREFIX"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "FIELD": "TEXT"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "FIELD": "TEXT"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to do this in simple_query_string, because other operators are needed too, for example, " \"sometext*\" | ( othertext -excludetext ) "

Comment: @Марат I have updated the answer. Simple query string can be replicated using bool query this will give better performance than wildcards